# How to describe the orientation of something in relation to two points?

Tags: expressions, syntactic-analysis, phrase-requests

Using simple English, how would I describe the orientation of an object in relation to two different objects -- one that's located on a vertical plane (object V) and another that's located on a horizontal plane (object H)?

> It's vertically oriented with object V, and it's horizontally oriented with object H.

This is the gist of what I'm trying to get across, but I feel like this is convoluted and not really as clear, simple, or elegant as it could be... I'm not sure what other constructions I could use.

### EDIT 1

To be more specific, I'm looking for a different construction than the one above. Are there any better ways to express this type of an orientation?

### EDIT 2 -- Illustration

I'm trying to describe the location of the thalamus in relation to the eyes and ears. So I might say:

> The thalamus is in the middle of the head, lined up vertically with the eyebrows and horizontally with the ears

Comment: the object is lined up vertically with object V and horizontally with  object H?

Comment: @Jim "lined up" is definitely more simple and your example is less redundant, thanks. I'm going to use this if I can't find a more simple construction -- i've edited my question to explain more clearly that I'm looking for a different construction

Comment: If I'm picturing this correctly, it forms a right angle with V and H—but maybe I'm not picturing it correctly? A very simple illustration might be helpful, if you can generate one. In graphic design, the term "aligned" would be used instead of "oriented".

Comment: @1006a ah i should have done that at the start, i edited my post to include a verbal illustration

Comment: Do the two planes intersect? If they do, it could be a right angle or something close to it.

Comment: The thalamus is in the center of the head on the level of the eyebrows back between with the ears.

Comment: You're trying to say that "the thalamus is located between the eye brows, in line with the ears.

Comment: But the thalamus is ***not*** "vertically aligned" with the eyebrows! It's right in the *middle* of the brain, and there aren't really any obvious candidates to be identified as directly above or below it (though maybe you could say it's straight up from the ***tonsils***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers when i say "vertically aligned" and "horizontally aligned" i'm trying to refer to its location on the transverse and coronal planes (in simpler terms)... because if you were to draw the transverse plane on the thalamus it would align pretty closely to the brow ridge... maybe I'm using the wrong terms?

Comment: @istols and Jim I'm torn between these two responses... they're both pretty perfect constructions! Thank you! I'm going to see if SE will let me answer my own question since these are in the comments section (not sure if there's a better way to mark one or both of your answers as a solution)

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley: I think you're using the wrong terms, yes.

Answer (score -1):

@istols and @Jim both provided excellent constructions in the comment section. Answering my own question in case someone else looks for a similar construction.

> the thalamus is located between the eye brows, in line with the ears

and

> The thalamus is in the center of the head on the level of the eyebrows back between the ears.

@FumbleFingers pointed out another point of reference that I never considered, *the tonsils*. A construction might be:

> The thalamus is in the middle of the head, directly above the tonsils at the level of the eyebrow ridge

Thanks!

Comment: Did I say, “between ***with*** the ears”???  I guess I did.  That’s a typo.   Delete the ***with***

Comment: This may be useful to the OP, but summarizing others' comments does not make an answer.